# Method_missing works, but const_missing does not work

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, method-missing

I have a simple ruby function:

```
module MyModule
    def foo(param)
      puts param
    end
end
```

I want to be able to make calls with undefined tokens like `bar` and `Baz`, as follows:

```
foo bar
foo Baz
```

Note that I need to be able to pass any token name that begins with an a letter (lower or upper case).

I can handle the first case (lower case beginning name, `bar`) by adding a method_missing:

```
module MyModule
  def method_missing(meth, *args, &blk)
    meth.to_s
  end
end
```

But the second line (with `Baz`) gives me an uninitialized constant error, so I tried adding a similar const_missing:

```
module MyModule
  def const_missing(const_name)
    const_name.to_s
  end
end
```

But I still get the uninitialized constant error with `Baz` - how do I trap missing names beginning with upper case and return the string?

Update: Here is the full code to repro the scenario:

```
module MyModule
  def foo(param)
    puts param
  end

  def method_missing(meth, *args, &blk)
    meth.to_s
  end

  def const_missing(const_name)
    const_name.to_s
  end
end

include MyModule
foo "bar" #=> bar
foo bar #=> bar
foo Baz #=> uninitialized constant Baz (NameError)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're doing in the examples?

Comment: As in are you trying `MyModule.foo(Baz)` or `MyModule.Baz`?

Comment: @cobaltsoda I want to support arbitrary tokens returning their string representation as part of a DSL I am building. In my example foo is a reserved keyword for the DSL, but bar and Baz are names that I want to pass in without passing in the string or symbol.

Comment: @cobaltsoda MyModule.foo(Baz)

Comment: Can you give working code, something that  can be pasted directly in irb? And why does `Module` start with capital letter?

Comment: I  can't get your `foo bar` to work. I assume it's ` MyModule.foo(MyModule::bar) `. I get an error: `NoMethodError: undefined method `bar' for MyModule:Module`

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš I fixed Module to module. You should be able to paste each snippet to reproduce

Comment: Look at my previous comment. I can't get your `foo bar`  to work meaning you need to edit your question so it's reproducible. Taking a break.

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš I have added the full repro code at the end.

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš - this does not work as expected in irb - but save it to a file and execute it from command line, and you get the results I mention.

Comment: I get `nil` as result of `p foo(bar)`, not `"bar"` as you wrote I should

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš You get `nil` because the `foo` method already does a `puts`, and returns `nil`.

Comment: Thank you. Answer coming soon.

Comment: I can reproduce the output on Ruby 2.1

Comment: @cobaltsoda Are u able to repro it inside irb? irb crashes with `identify_identifier: can't convert NilClass to Array (NilClass#to_ary gives String) (TypeError)` - I have ruby 2.3

Comment: Everyone who downvoted, this is a good question now when it's reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

If you want to be able to write just `Baz` then you need to define `Object.const_missing`  and make it call `MyModule.const_missing`.

```
def Object.const_missing(const_name)
  MyModule.const_missing(const_name)
end
```

### Explanation

You are getting an error because there is no constant `Baz` in current scope which is main ruby's object `Object`.

This is better, more revealing test code:

```
include MyModule
p foo(bar)
p bar
p MyModule.Baz
p Baz
```

Output is this:

```
bar # 1
nil # from puts
"bar" # 2
"Baz" # 3
test.rb:19:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Baz (NameError) # 4
```

1. `foo bar` calls method foo, method missing is never called.
2. `bar` searches for method in current object then calls method_missing on `Object` which is found in it's included `MyModule`
3. `MyModule.Baz` searches for constant in module MyModule and then calls `const_missing`.
4. `Baz` searches for constant_missing in current module and it calls `const_missing` which is `Object.const_missing`, Object's class instance method.

When ruby looks up methods it starts with object methods and only when it can't define them it looks into it's modules, then parent class, then parent classes modules etc. It is not possible to override objects/classes method from it's module.

`Object` (ruby's main object which includes Kernel) has defined it's `const_missing` method, but not `method_missing`.

```
search = "method_"
Object.public_methods.select { |s| s.to_s.include?(search) }
=> [:method_defined?, :public_method_defined?, 
:private_method_defined?, :protected_method_defined?]
```

Notice no method missing. Searching for `const_` does find `const_missing`

```
search = "const_"
=> "const_"
irb(main):011:0> Object.public_methods.select { |s| s.to_s.include?(search) }
=> [:const_get, :const_defined?, :const_set, :const_missing]
```

Comment: The `Object.const_missing` response worked for me, with some modifications. I don't understand (3) in your explanation above. Why would `MyModule.Baz` trigger method_missing? `Baz` starts with an upper case letter, so wouldn't it directly look for `const_missing`?